# Advanced Custom Fields - Compare Datepicker Date with current date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need help to display a simple message when one of my seminars ends. I have something like "*This seminar has ended*" in mind, but can't figure out the right formats. I'm using wordpress and the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) (ACF) plugin for custom fields:

**Code:**

```
    <?php 

        $today = date('Ymd');
        $sem_date = get_field('sem_date'); // Output format d / m / y  (has to be this format on the site)

        if($today > $sem_date){ ?>

        <div class="oops">
            This seminar has ended!
        </div>  

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get today's date as a Date Object:

```
$today = new DateTime( 'today', new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago') );
```

Get seminar's date as a Date Object:

```
$sem_date = new DateTime( get_field('sem_date') );
```

Now you can compare the two Date objects:

```
$today > $sem_date
```